# Blogger atom feeds doesn't return all the data. How to deal with it?

Tags: blogger

The GET request to this url only returns 27 posts out of 120. I tried various other blogs but got similar results. Is it not possible to retrieve all the posts using the feeds of a blogger blog?

```
http://www.blogger.com/feeds/blogID/posts/default
```

Answer (score 0):

The default url fetches only 25-27..

Try this to get 1st to get 500 posts

http://www.BLOG.blogspot.com/atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500

for next 500 posts

http://www.BLOG.blogspot.com/atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=501&max-results=500

and so on